# Python and snmpset with netsnmp

Tags: linux, python, snmp

On the linux command line, centos 7, I can to do this to change an snmp setting on a device.

snmpset -v 2c -c private 172.16.1.2 .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0 s new_name

With python and netsnmp I can read the values I just cannot seem to change them.

```
import netsnmp

line = "172.16.1.2"
snmp_string = "private"

oid = netsnmp.Varbind('.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0')
result = netsnmp.snmpget(oid, Version = 2, DestHost=line, Community=snmp_string)

print result
```

The above works fine to read the value can anyone tell me how to write to the value with python preferably using netsnmp?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
oid = netsnmp.Varbind('.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0',"new_name","STRING")
```

You have to tell what's the type of value and pass the value.